# Why did S.H.I.E.L.D. leave such an important object so undefended?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

This question is about the end of season three of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.

After they

> trap Hive in a gel matrix and take him back to base

they just leave it in the hangar with the hangar doors wide open and a couple mall cops.

I understand the hangar doors were still damaged, but why leave it out there? That's idiotic and makes no sense. This was a terrible black spot on an otherwise good episode and season. Or, if it needed to be out there for some unexplained reason, why not put it under heavy guard? Even after the bomb went off, a couple of guards with guns could have solved things with bullets.

In all likelihood, everything would have been fine if they'd just taken some reasonable precautions. I guess that's what Coulson meant by "our mistakes"?

Comment: and the fact that the doctor Shot a Primitive with a normal gun, but Shield operatives' gun was useless.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it was left out in the dock was because there was no adequate storage facility ready inside the base, and Fitz needed to be there to oversee the transport.

There was no reason for the lack of guard duty, at least heavier guarding or one of the tougher veterans such as Mack or May should have been guarding it at all times, especially since there were known operatives still at the loose.

The reason they couldn't get the situation under control was because they were using icers which have no effect on the intruders. Bullets would have been the far better choice as we know they work, however SHIELD are known for using more non-lethal tactics hence the guards being equipped with icers.

I believe the mistake Coulson was referring to was when he 'crossed the line' as he mentioned in the episode. He sees that event as the catalyst that allowed it all to happen.

That was my take on it all!

Comment: Great first post! Normally, answers on this site are upvoted more if they provide some form of support to the claims they make. Are there any quotes or specific events which support your points?

Comment: I think the reason for the "lack of guard duty" was that they didn't feel it was necessary. They were obviously wrong, but I got the impression they kind of felt like it was finally over and they were safe. Maybe they expected those working with Hive to just stop once they were without a leader.

Comment: Did they actually *say* that there was no adequate storage at some point? I mean, even the hallway inside the main door would have been better than out in the hangar.

Comment: I don't have the episode to hand, but at one stage Fitz mentioned something about making sure a power supply (or something similar) was hooked up. So it could have just been delayed if Fitz was unavailable as soon as the plane landed. 
I'll watch it again later for the full dialogue.